# How to add or delete default value theme options while activate and deactivate theme

Tags: functions, hooks, theme-options

I want to add & reset default value for my theme options while activate and deactivate a theme

More clearly something like this

```
if(theme active)
  add_option(); 
  // add new option to the theme and register default setting for one time only

if(theme deactivate)
   delete_option();
  // reset current option and delete default setting  for one time only
```

Question

How know is theme active or not? What a function or hook for this one. Let me know

Comment: possible duplicate : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6248/theme-activate-hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for was answered here:

- [**Theme Activate Hook**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6248/theme-activate-hook)