# How to determine when my theme is deactivated?

Tags: theme-development

I'm using the following code branch to execute some theme setup options...

```
$myTheme_initialized = get_option('myTheme_initialized');
if (is_admin() && !$myTheme_initialized && isset($_GET['activated'] ) ) {
//do setup stuff
}
```

What hook can I tap into when the theme is deactivated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.krishnakantsharma.com/2011/01/activationdeactivation-hook-for-wordpress-theme/#

Pretty good writeup for activation and deactivation

Same thing is here on SE
[Theme Activate Hook](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6248/theme-activate-hook)