# Create Child Taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

Is there a way to use the `register_taxonomy` function to create child taxonomies to a specific parent taxonomy in a hierarchical structure?

For example: Let's say I'm creating a theme for selling cars where users can activate it and it automatically creates a hierarchical taxonomy called "Make".  Is there any way to have it automatically create a few different vehicle "make" taxonomies, say Toyota, Lexus, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean you want to create terms in your taxonomy?

Have a look at [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6248/theme-activate-hook) for detecting when a theme is activated.

Then use [wp_insert_term](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) to insert the terms into your taxonomy.