# after_setup_theme always runs

Tags: theme-development, themes, actions, bug

I am setting up a child theme for some of my faculty members, and as a part of the theme, I would like a handful of plugins to be activated at the time that the theme is activated.  So, naturally, I used the after_setup_theme action and called my setup function.  It works great, except it runs on EVERY request (admin and otherwise).  I proved this by adding this to the end of the setup function:

`echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("This action was run")</script>';`

And as a result get a javascript alert on every admin request and every front-end request (I have a network setup, so obviously on sites where this theme is not active, it's not running the function)

So the question is, is this a bug?  Am I somehow doing something wrong?  Here is the complete code that I am using:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'fwp_setup' );
function fwp_setup(){
    // -- Unrelated code remove for the sake of brevity 
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php');
    activate_plugin('enable-media-replace/enable-media-replace.php');
    activate_plugin('seo-image/seo-friendly-images.php');
    activate_plugin('w3-total-cache/w3-total-cache.php');
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("This action was run")</script>';
}
```

Any insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: SOLUTION: 
`after_switch_theme` does exactly what I intended here.  It fires after the theme is switched TO your theme. One of the solutions mentioned below uses `switch_theme`.  This does not have the desired results, since it only happens upon switching away from your theme. [Reference this Trac comment](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/7795#comment:29)

Comment: please post that as an *answer*, rather than as a *comment* to your question. :)

Comment: Apologies.  It would not let me do that yet.  I will add it as an answer in a bit.

Answer (score 10):

SOLUTION: `after_switch_theme` does exactly what I intended here. It fires after the theme is switched TO your theme. One of the solutions mentioned below uses `switch_theme`. This does not have the desired results, since it only happens upon switching away from your theme.

Here is an article that I found as reference: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/7795#comment:29

Here is my modified code

```
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'fwp_theme_setup' );
function fwp_theme_setup(){ 
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php');
    activate_plugin('enable-media-replace/enable-media-replace.php');
    activate_plugin('seo-image/seo-friendly-images.php');
    activate_plugin('w3-total-cache/w3-total-cache.php');
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `after_setup_theme` action is **intended** to fire on every WordPress load. It is simply part of the process during which WordPress invokes the template system, determines the various setup parameters for the Theme, and then proceeds on with subsequent processing, such as determining the correct template to display, etc.

In other words, the `after_setup_theme` represents the point at which **WordPress** sets up the current Theme, *not* the point at which the **administrator** *activates and/or configures* the current Theme.

What you're looking for is a Theme **activation** hook, which currently isn't available, but [is under consideration/development](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/7795).

Comment: The Codex entry [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_setup_theme) is terribly misleading then.    It says "This hook is called during a themes initialization."  That means, to me, that the hook should be called when it's activated.  I understand what you're saying though.  Terribly misleading.

Comment: `init !== activation`. Normally you call `__construct()` function in php also an `init` function. That means: Initialize the instance.

Comment: The trac ticket is 7 years old and seems won't be fixed!

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is no theme-activation hook. However, a [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6248/theme-activate-hook) does provide a work-around for that.

Simply use the 'theme activation hook' to activate the plug-ins.

A better solution, along the same vein [is this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566921/wordpress-custom-theme-execute-setup-code-on-activation-only). Both essentially use the `switch_theme` hook.

---

As per the OP comments and the [linked trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/7795#comment:29) -  `after_switch_theme` is the hook required.

This passes the old theme's name as an argument. However, if this is in your `functions.php` (which it should be...) the callback will *only fire when your theme is being activated*.

```
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'wpse50298_setup' );
function wpse50298_setup($theme_switching_from){
    // Your theme is being activated
}
```

Similarly add a callback to `switch_theme` will only be called when your theme is de-activated.

```
add_action( 'switch_theme', 'wpse50298_deactivate' );
function wpse50298_deactivate($theme_switching_to){
    // Your theme is being deactivated
}
```

Comment: Neither of these options worked for me.  `switch_theme` only worked after deactivting the theme.  However, `after_switch_theme` worked perfectly.

Comment: updated answer :)

Comment: switch_theme doesn't seem to work anymore. I think it is because of the changes in 3.4 activation. At least it isn't working for me.

Comment: after_switch_theme works perfect. This should be the accepted answer. I am using WP 3.5

Answer (score 0):

A better solution might be to use [Thomas Griffin's plugin activation script](https://github.com/thomasgriffin/TGM-Plugin-Activation). This will prompt users to install plugins of your choice when the theme is in use. I think this is a great way to separate the plugin from the theme, and still get the use of it.

Within your theme, check if the plugin is active before using it's functions. This will allow users more choice and control.

You can set up the activation script easily with [Knapsack](http://wpcandy.com/labs/knapsack).

Comment: [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). Please add a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your best fix would be now to use `switch_theme` hook and filter the passed '$theme' argument to see if it is the current them then if not return;

```
function nw_update_network($theme) {
   if ($theme !== 'my_theme_name') return;

   // Your code here
}

add_action('switch_theme', 'nw_update_network');
```