# How to include wp-postviews plugin directly in the theme

Tags: plugins

I don't want to ask the user to install this and that plugin, I want my theme to be 100% active active without the need to install a plugin like [wp-postviews](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postviews/) plugin, so how can i do that. I want to include it directly in functions.php file?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That was so easy! I just included the plugin folder in my theme Then i included it.

```
 include(your-theme-path . 'wp-postviews/wp-postviews.php');
```

That was it!

Answer (score 0):

You could include the particular plugin in your theme directory and then fire a function on `after_switch_theme`:

```
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'fwp_theme_setup' );
function fwp_theme_setup(){ 
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php');
    activate_plugin('your-theme/plugin-dir/plugin.php');
}
```

You should also take a look at [after_setup_theme always runs](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50298/after-setup-theme-always-runs)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, but it doesn't work, I found a solution though, you can find it in my answer below.