# Develop theme with demo default content, programmatically create pages

Tags: theme-development

I am creating a theme and was wondering if there is a function or some way I could have it automatically create some specific pages on setup.  Would this have to be an XML import?  For example the theme depends on a couple of specific pages being created. The content is not important but ideally need to have a page called projects and tags that use their own unique template files.  Could I create these pages programmatically and not require using the CMS.  They are just being used as archive pages.

Comment: if you use a projects post type you would get this for free without any pages, and it would have its own REST API endpoints, RSS feeds, WP Admin menu, and SEO/Sitemap support. I'm guessing that you've currently implemented these as page templates and are using child pages to do this rather than implementing your seperate content type as a seperate content type?

Comment: also it's not considered proper to do this unprompted without warning, you would be much better checking if the pages exist then prompting the user with a button that creates them so that it isn't a surprise

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tom, I agree it is questionable to do this without warning, I am exploring my options and it is valid consideration.  I actually originally did have custom post types, and then switched them back to core category and tags... now I am again rethinking that, argh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `after_setup_theme` create your post and tags then save the data, add option key and only run your setup once,

i.e.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme',  function() {
    
    $setupKey = 'my_theme_activated';

    $setupAlreadyRun = get_option($setupKey);

    if ( $setupAlreadyRun )
        return;

    my_theme_setup( $setupKey );

});


function my_theme_setup( $setupKey ) {
    $posts = [
        [
            'post_title'        => 'Project Page',
            'post_type'         => 'page',
            'post_status'       => 'publish'
        ],
        [
            'post_title'        => 'Another Project Page',
            'post_type'         => 'page',
            'post_status'       => 'publish'
        ],
        [
            'post_title'        => 'Another Last Project Page',
            'post_type'         => 'page',
            'post_status'       => 'publish'
        ]
    ];

    $postIDs = [];

    foreach( $posts as $post ) {
        $postIDs[] = wp_insert_post( $post );
    }

    $tag = wp_insert_term('My Project Tag', 'post_tag');

    // What else you want to do here.



    //Save data in options table in case you want to do something with the automated setup ids, 
    if ( is_array( $tag ) && isset( $tag['term_id'] ) )
        update_option('my_auto_setup_tag', $tag['term_id']);

    update_option('my_auto_setup_pages', implode(',', $postIDs ) );
    update_option($setupKey, 1 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @silver I will explore this.. also found this novella about how to do it with XML files...   https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96227/import-wordpress-xml-file-from-within-functions-php

Comment: yes you can use XML format, but it would prefer o just use json format and add the arrays of pages in there, read the files in php, decode the json, and loop throught then use `wp_Insert_post` or  use raw query builder so you can create all the pages in a single query