# How to make permalinks update from code?

Tags: theme-development, permalinks

I have made made a theme that has some 'virtual' pages made with url_rewrite. Is there any way of updating the permalink options at theme install so the pages are availble from start, with out requiring the user to update them from Dashboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is difficult to understand but I think what you want is to run [`flush_rewrite_rules()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) on theme activation. I don't believe there is a specialized hook for this but both @Rarst and @toscho have posted good methods [in another answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/6248/21376). You should be able to easily adapt that code.

Comment: Thank you. I known how to implement it with hooks, just wanted to know the function. :D